# imageview in list row gets highlighted on tap of any area on row

Tags: android, android-listview, selector, android-imageview

A listview row has a clickable image at the right end of the row.
I have applied a selector on the image(blue background on click)
On touch of any part of a row, the image changes colour.
I want it to show the blue background only on tap of the imageview area

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sample"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:duplicateParentState="false"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            >
        </ImageView>
```

Comment: The whole row is clickable and everything (inside it) is part of it.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your imageView has focus and consume click events in listview so you must add this:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sample"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:duplicateParentState="false"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"

        android:focusable="false"

    </ImageView>
```

now if you set imageView click listener in right place (inside adapter getView) when you click on it, it change and when you click on other list item view it wont respond.

you can also do it in another way. instead of using imageView click listener use listItemclick listener and use the view pass to you and find out which item is clicked by using View·getCurrentFocus() to see if it is your imageview or not.